# Issues with custom scorer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am doing some online lessons in machine learning, and we use the following scoring function in our DNN models for regression:

```
    def r_squared(y_true, y_pred):
        # 1 - ((y_i - y_hat_i)^2 / (y_i - y_sum)^2)

        numerator = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(y_true, y_pred)))
        denominator = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(y_pred, tf.reduce_mean(y_true))))
        r2 = tf.clip_by_value(tf.subtract(1.0, tf.div(numerator, denominator)), clip_value_min = 0.0, clip_value_max = 1.0)

        return r2

... later ...

        model.compile(loss = "mse", # mean-square-error,
                    optimizer = optimizer(lr = learning_rate),
                    metrics = [r_squared])
```

Now while the model and all is working, I wanted to conduct a gridsearch to determine the best parameters for my model. However, when trying to use the `r_squared` function with the gridsearch as scorer, I get several errors:

```
        grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = estimator, 
                            param_grid = param_grid,
                            n_jobs = 1,
                            verbose = 1,
                            cv = folds,
                            scoring = make_scorer(FeedForward.r_squared, greater_is_better=True))
```

results in:

```
TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Sub' Op has type float64 that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'.
```

around here:

```
r2 = tf.clip_by_value(tf.subtract(1.0, tf.div(numerator, denominator)), clip_value_min = 0.0, clip_value_max = 1.0)
```

Thus, I changed the line as follows:

```
r2 = tf.clip_by_value(tf.subtract(1.0, tf.div(tf.cast(numerator, tf.float32), tf.cast(denominator, tf.float32))), clip_value_min = 0.0, clip_value_max = 1.0)
```

which then results in:

```
ValueError: scoring must return a number, got Tensor("mul:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) (<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>) instead. (scorer=score)
```

While I understand the error and can confirm it in the debugger, I find myself unable to resolve the issue even with googling for the error. Which might be due to - unnecessary to mention - be beeing not familiar enough yet with tensorflow.

So how to I get the value out of the tensor? And am I even doing the right thing here, or is something else wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is mixing the usage of TensorFlow/Keras and scikit-learn. A Keras metric needs to be implemented using `keras.backend` functions, but scikit-learn functions are not symbolic and have to be implemented using numpy.

Fortunately scikit-learn already has an implementation of the R^2 score as `sklearn.metrics.r2_score`, so you can use it like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = estimator, 
                            param_grid = param_grid,
                            n_jobs = 1,
                            verbose = 1,
                            cv = folds,
                            scoring = make_scorer(r2_score, greater_is_better=True))
```

Your Keras metric needs no change, its a bit odd that you have to keep two implementations of the metric, but it is like that.

Comment: I tried this out, however the classification is giving different values for the r2 from sklearn as my training metric with my custom `r_squared` function. 
After 100 epochs, `r_squared` will be trained to 0.63 (close to 1 is better) while the classification will yield a result like this:
`Best: -3.003969 using {'layers': [64], 'learning_rate': 0.005, 'optimizer': <class 'keras.optimizers.Adam'>}` after 100 epochs with the same parameters. So it seems like the `sklearn.metrics.r2_score` is not calculating the same metric.

Comment: @user826955 I don't get what you mean by "the classification", it could be that your R2 implementation is not correct. I trust more the sklearn implementation.

Comment: The grid search. Appearently, the `sklearn.metrics.r2_score` function yields a different number than my `r_squared` (because the implementation appearently is different). That means, I want to use my `r_squared` function in the `GridSearchCV`, so I can compare the output to my normal traning runs (which also use my `r_squared` function).